# issue in inserting data in sqlite database

Tags: ios, sqlite

this is how i try to add data in sqlite database everything works perfectly but data is not getting added in database i dont understand why can you please refer the code and tell me what am i doing wrong

```
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
    int x;

    char *update = "insert into PersonNamesAndBirthDates (Names,Birthdates,Phonenumber,Email,Profilepic) values(?,?,?,?,?);";
    x = sqlite3_prepare_v2(database1, update, -1, &stmt, nil);

    if (x == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"PersonName is -->%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[_Namebarray objectAtIndex:0]]);
        NSLog(@"BirthDates is -->%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[_Birthdatebarray objectAtIndex:0]]);
        NSLog(@"BirthDates is -->%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[_Phonearray objectAtIndex:0]]);
        NSLog(@"BirthDates is -->%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[_Emailarray objectAtIndex:0]]);
        // if else will come here for checking weather images has added or not if added then store Yes Image if not then simply No image for default image.


        sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[_Namebarray objectAtIndex:0]] UTF8String],-1, NULL);
        sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 2, [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[_Birthdatebarray objectAtIndex:0]] UTF8String],-1, NULL);
        sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 3, [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[_Phonearray objectAtIndex:0]] UTF8String],-1, NULL);
        sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 4, [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[_Emailarray objectAtIndex:0]] UTF8String],-1, NULL);
        if(selectImage.image)
        {
            sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 5, [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[_arrayOfPaths objectAtIndex:0]] UTF8String],-1, NULL);
        }
        else{
            sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 5, [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"No Image"] UTF8String],-1, NULL);
        }
    }
    if (sqlite3_step(stmt) != SQLITE_DONE){}
    NSLog(@"Error: ");
    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
```

Comment: what do you mean with *data is not getting added in database*?, are you getting an error?

Comment: i am getting no error just database is not getting filled

Comment: where is you database file stored, in the app bundle or in the documents dir?

Comment: the NSLog calls are getting executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no error in your Code do check that your database is open like this

```
if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database1) == SQLITE_OK)
```

Comment: Further, the return code really should be captured and the value logged if not SQLITE_OK, plus one should log the result of calling sqlite3_errmsg if not OK.  Especially when becoming familiar with SQLite, one should make a point to check and log every "abnormal" return code.

Answer (score 0):

There is an example project for using SQLite here: https://github.com/AaronBratcher/ABSQLite

It has code in there for adding and reading data.